# Centering UIView in middle of superview springs/struts

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a basic question regarding springs/struts (I'm working on a legacy codebase that prefers it over auto layout), and since I started iOS using auto layout I am trying to understand why this doesnt work. I am wanting to simply center this UIView in superview.

What I have (notice my springs/struts settings):

[image]

So with that, it views just fine on an iPhone 5 screen.

Here is what iPhone 4 screen displays though:

[image]

As you can see, it is much lower than what it should be. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you set the top and bottom margin to be **fixed**. Try removing them from the storyboard, and you'll see that your view will be centered vertically.